# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when passing NSDate to pointer

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, exc-bad-access

I'm getting this error in the commented line.
datachoice is an Object of UserData, which is external but I imported it.
I retained datesave in the .h as well I don't know what Is join on, something with out release probably???

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DateViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datepick;
@property (strong, retain) IBOutlet NSDate *datesave;


- (IBAction)okDatebutton:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)okDatebutton:(id)sender {

datesave = [datepick date];
datechoice->date = datesave; //<-----------------here is the EXC_BAD_ACCESS



}
@end
```

Comment: Try adding an `NSLog("%p", datechoice)` right after the assignment to `datesave`, and see if non-null gets printed to the log.

Comment: What do you mean by: *"datachoice is an Object of UserData, which is external but I imported it."*? Can you show the corresponding code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never(*) use the `->` operator for objects. You meant:

```
self.datechoice.date = datesave;
```

(*) There's an [obscure exception](http://robnapier.net/blog/implementing-nscopying-439) to this rule where it can be required, but it doesn't apply to iOS, only Mac.

Comment: It looks like the datachoice is an `extern`-ed global, so the OP probably did not want to do `self`.

Comment: <offtopic>thanks for the book, it's an interesting read :)</offtopic>

Comment: I can't do self because date choice is external object of UserDate, or can I? I might not understand what you mean, thanks..

Comment: go it, just removed strong, and changed the -> to a dot

Comment: I see what you mean; it is generally a bad idea to have global mutable objects (the singleton pattern is preferred, or even class methods), but I see your point. You should definitely use some naming convention to make it clear that this is a global. @dasblinkenlight Glad you like it. Thanks.

Comment: I did have to add @porperty in UserData.h, before I just had NSDate. Everything works nicely. Thank You so much. I'm a total beginner and don't know how I got this far lol

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ARC? I think your property definitions look wrong.

If I recall correctly, `strong` is only valid with ARC, and `retain` is only valid without ARC. I'm surprised it lets you compile if that's the problem though.

Comment: `retain` is valid under ARC. It's treated as a synonym for `strong`. You're right that the definitions are wrong, but I don't think that's the cause.

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct. Thought it looked odd! @user1191343 if you're using ARC the convention would be `(nonatomic, strong)` or `(nonatomic, weak)` depending on what type of ownership you need.